Omen laptop and 144hz external monitor
I have Omen laptop  (15-dc0005ne) which has

1 USB 3.1 Type-C Gen 1 (Data Transfer up to 5 Gb/s, DP1.2, HP Sleep and Charge)
3 USB 3.1 Gen 1 (1 HP Sleep and Charge)

I tried to connect it to an external monitor 4K UHD 144hz using different cables and the refresh rate is always 60hz. I used HDMI 2.1 cable, provided USB-C cable, USB-C to DisplayPort adapter and the result is the same: 60hz
Does anyone have a solution for this issue?
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06068786

3840×2160 at 144 Hz requires a tremendous amount of bandwidth. The only connections that can handle this uncompressed are:

DisplayPort 2.0+ (4 lanes)
HDMI 2.1+

tl;dr: It’s not happening.
Your laptop probably does not support any of that. Instead, you have DisplayPort 1.2 and maybe HDMI 2.0, but more likely less. Further complicating this is the fact that most adapters (cables or otherwise) from USB-C (host) to DisplayPort (display) only have 2 lanes, so half the bandwidth. Without display compression, you can achieve:

3840×2160 at 60 Hz on DisplayPort 1.2 (2 lanes)
3840×2160 at 60 Hz on HDMI 2.0 (4:4:4 colors)
3840×2160 at 120 Hz on HDMI 2.0 (4:2:0 colors)
3840×2160 at 75 Hz on HDMI 1.3 (4:2:0 colors)

Unfortunately, your GPU does not support DSC (Display Stream Compression), so better results are mostly out of the question.
